# Check a range of text against a text string and return "yes" or "no"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of text strings (titles) and a list of "bad" keywords I want to identify within those titles.

The problem I've run into is how to identify individual text within the string. Several simple formulas can do this for an exact match, but I need it to identify words within the titles.

For example, in "Software sales representative" I need it to recognize "software" is on the list and return the word "bad".

I've browsed other questions on here and there's nothing that answers this specifically on Stacked.

The other similar questions have said this can be done with a asterisk/ wildcard, but this does not work. I know conditional formatting can do this, but I need a formula since I have over 100 "bad" keywords.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(K:K,"*"&E2&"*"),"Bad","Okay")
```

But this formula still only returns exact matches.

Column E is the titles. Column K is the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$1:INDEX(K:K,MATCH("zzz",K:K)),E2)))),"Bad","Okay")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this Function in a module and call it from a cell like this `=ContainsBadwords(badwordsrange,rangetotest;false;false)`

```
Public Function ContainsBadwords(BadWordList As range, ByVal SuspectRange As range, Optional ExactMatch As Boolean = True, Optional CaseSensitive As Boolean = True)
For Each ArrayItem In SuspectRange
If Not CaseSensitive Then ArrayItem = Strings.lcase(ArrayItem)

        For Each Subwhat In BadWordList
        If ExactMatch Then
        test = (ArrayItem = Subwhat)
        Else
        test = InStr(ArrayItem, Subwhat) >= 1
        End If
        If test Then: ContainsBadwords = test: Exit Function
        Next Subwhat
If test Then: ContainsBadwords = test: Exit Function
n = n + 1
Next ArrayItem
End Function
```

Returns TRUE for blasphemy or FALSE if no bad words exist.